# Getting data from Google Play Leaderboards

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, leaderboard

I wanted to know if there is a way to get diffrent players scores, country etc from a leaderboard(Without opening Play Games App)(Like returning a String).

Example 1: To know the player with the highest score in the leaderboard(Without opening Play Games App)

Example 2: To know the players immediately above and below the current player in the leaderboard(Without Opening play Games App)

Any ideas on how to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can write a [web app](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/leaderboards) that pulls the data. I'm not sure the extent of what information can be retreieved though. Whatever is in the [JSON response](https://developers.google.com/games/services/web/api/scores) is up for grabs. Anything else, you probably can't retrieve.

Comment: Instead of writing a web app can't I pull data into my android activity??? @Andy

Comment: You definitely can still use it with [Android](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards). Apologies, for whatever reason it sounded to me like you wanted to do it outside Android.

Comment: Thanku I Will try...... Give me any sample code or pointers if you have an idea... @Andy

Comment: The docs previously linked and the [TypeANumber sample](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples) covers leaderboards pretty well.